# How to generate SqlFunctions.DateDiff dynamically

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table with multiple columns of type `DateTime`. I want to generate dynamically the following `Expression`

```
filter= p => SqlFunctions.DateDiff("day", p.CreatedDate.Date, date) > 0;
```

when I know the name of column and the operator (the operator can be `=`, `>=`,  `<=` and etc... .

Please, keep in mind that I want to ignore the time part form `Datetime`

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you use `SqlFunctions.DateDiff`, that must mean that you're working in linq to entities. So I don't think you can use `p.CreatedDate.Date`, but you'll have to use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(p.CreatedDate)`.

Anyway.

You could go for something like that (just the general idea, this should be of course improved).

assuming that `p` type is `Employee`

```
public static class ExpressionHelper {
   //we create a Dictionary to manage the comparison operators, 
   //which will probably make things easier when calling the main method.
   public static Dictionary<string, ExpressionType> Comparators = new Dictionary<string, ExpressionType>
        {
            {">", ExpressionType.GreaterThan},
            {">=", ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual},
            {"<", ExpressionType.LessThan},
            {"<=", ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual}
        };

   public static Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> BuildFilterExpression(string datePart, DateTime date, string comparisonOperator)
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (Employee), "p");
            Expression member = parameter;
            //the property is a string here, it could be passed as parameter
            //or managed another way
            member = Expression.Property(member, "CreatedDate");
            //let's find the dateDiffMethod
            var dateDiffMethod = typeof (SqlFunctions).GetMethod("DateDiff", new[] {typeof (string), typeof (DateTime), typeof(DateTime)});
            //same for TruncateTime method
            var truncateTimeMethod = typeof (EntityFunctions).GetMethod("TruncateTime", new[] {typeof (DateTime)});
            //first call truncateTime method (to keep only "Date" part)
            var truncateExpression = Expression.Call(truncateTimeMethod, member);
            //call dateDiff method on that
            var dateDiffExpression = Expression.Call(dateDiffMethod, Expression.Constant(datePart), truncateExpression, Expression.Constant(date, typeof(DateTime?)));
            //find the comparison operator
            var comparator = Comparators[comparisonOperator];
            //apply the comparison
            var finalExpression = Expression.MakeBinary(comparator, dateDiffExpression, Expression.Constant(0, typeof(int?)));
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<Employee, bool>>(finalExpression, new []{parameter});
        }
}
```

usage, with your code would be something like that

```
filter = ExpressionHelper.BuildFilterExpression("day", date, ">")
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work just for columns which are `DateTime?` because the `DateDiff` function doesn't  accepts `DateTime` as parameter. Any Ideas how can I sole it for columns which have type `DateTime`?

Comment: I solve it, I added `Expression.Convert` to convert `DateTime` to `DateTime?`

Comment: @roroinpho21 Fine. By the way, I see that you never accept answers. This would be a good thing to do, as it shows that you have found the desired answer, and show the question as closed for other users.